# Is it possible to deserialize a Shape in C# using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, shapes

EDITED

Is it possible to deserialize a c# Object which as a Shape as attribute?

I have a Touch object, which inherits from a Circle Object, which inherits from a Obstacle Object which as a Shape as attribute.

I serialize a Touch object to json like this :

```
        Touch touch = new Touch(0.15, 0, 4.05);
        touch.Shape.Stroke = Brushes.Black;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(touch);
```

I would like to deserialize this object, using his json, like this :

```
        Touch test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Touch>(json);
```

But I get an access violation with this line of code.

I think it comes from the Shape attribute in my Obstacle Object, which is declarated like this :

```
        protected Shape shape;

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Shape")]
        public Shape Shape
        {
            get { return shape; }
            set { this.shape = value; }
        }
```

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Try encapsulating it

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Do you have a JSON Document with Shape objects that need to be deserialized into C# objects, or do you have C# objects that you want to serialize to JSON?

Comment: Also, this is simply the class that could hold the data - can you show how you perform the serialization / deserialization?

Comment: Hello @LarsKristensen, I would like to get JSON from a REST API and you it to create objects in my app. I just completed my first post, hope you can help me achieve this task ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to my serialization.
I just deleted my Shape from the Json Serialization using `[JsonIgnore]`, and i create it with a method. I just need two lines instead of one to create my object by serialization:

```
Touch test = JsonConverter.Deserialize<Touch>(json);
test.CreateShape();
```

Thank you for your help =)

Comment: But this will not deserialize any Shape stored in Json - it will simply create a new Shape, once you deserialize the Touch object.

Comment: Every objects that I create create a proper Shape too, so, it's not a problem for now =)

Comment: Well okay, if it works for you - this may have solved the problem you had, but it didn't answer the question you asked.

Comment: I think it's impossible to deserialize Shape for now.
If you want to deserialize something, you have to prepare models, using the `[JsonProperty(PropertyName= "something"]` typo, which is not set in the Shape code. So, we have to create a Shape object for each Deserialized object